# MS Word: regex for identifying hyperlinks

Tags: regex, hyperlink, ms-word, wildcard

I am working on books. Part of my brief is to find and remove hyperlinks.

Commonly these are hidden underneath citations, so can be very hard to identify as they look identical to surrounding text.

E.g. something like "(1876) 1 CPD 691 at 701" can look like text but has an underlying hyperlink. Mouse hovering works to ID them but takes an age, especially when there are 1000s in footnotes! :)

The books are all styled using custom, in-house MS Word styles so the in-built Find > Format > Style > Hyperlink doesn't work.

Is there a Word regex that can identify hyperlinks in Word docs using the Find function using Wildcards? I searched existing questions but couldn't find anything that looked to match my needs...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this: Press `Alt+F9` to enable field codes. It will show the word HYPERLINK for each link. Then just press `Ctrl + F` and enter `^d HYPERLINK`.